# Failed to disable compiler warning from command line on Visual Studio compiler

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, compiler-warnings

I got a weird problem with MSVC9(Microsoft Visual Studio 2008). I CANNOT disable the warning, C4214, with command line by cl.exe, but it works with `#pragma warning(disable: 4214)` in source code. I tried with another nonstandard extension warning, C4200, it can be disabled both with command line and pragma. Does anyone know why this might be? My complete command

```
/Od /Oi /GL /D "__WIN32__" /D "_UNICODE" /D "_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE=1" /FD /RTC1 /MT /Gy /W4 /WX /wd4115 /wd4127 /wd4214 /wd4200 /nologo /c /Zi /TC /errorReport:prompt
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `/wd4214` in your command line. That should be sufficient. Checkout this [MSDN Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-option-warning-level).

Answer (score 0):

You could test with:
`/Od /Oi /GL /D "__WIN32__" /D "_UNICODE" /D "_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE=1" /FD /RTC1 /MT /Gy /W4 /WX /wd4115;4127;4214;4200 /nologo /c /Zi /TC /errorReport:prompt`